# Is it possible to sign-off a Merge Commit in Git?

Tags: git, git-merge, atlassian-sourcetree

I have to sign off my every commit to push to the origin. However, merge commits are not signed off, I use sourcetree and also the git console, could not sign-off a merge commit. Is there a way that could be done?

Comment: `git merge --signoff` is coming with Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46028114/6309).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run `git commit --amend --no-edit -s` after merge is done.

Comment: For Git > 2.15, you can use:
```git merge --signoff``` 

Reference:
- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt---signoff
- https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.15.0.txt

Comment: and you should use `-S` instead of `-s` if you need to verify the signature (i.e. using GPG)

Answer (score 6):

You can do a merge without committing:

```
git merge --no-commit
```

Git prepares everything for committing. After that you finish the merge with

```
git commit -s
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're lucky, `--signoff` will be added as a parameter to git merge. Seems like there's work going on, see [this patch](https://public-inbox.org/git/0102015d0c41db74-34ff8613-05e2-44bb-a05b-2624108c36c8-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com/) from earlier this month.

Until then, the other answers will do. However, I want to suggest adding an alias for easyness. For instance, add the following to your `.git/config` file.

```
[alias]
    merge-signed = !git merge --no-commit $1 && git commit -is
```

And then:

```
git merge-signed feature
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will be possible for Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q3 2017)

See [commit 14d01b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14d01b4f07a08ee55bffc74f2d6e1b0a4e8ce900) (04 Jul 2017) by [Łukasz Gryglicki (`lukaszgryglicki`)](https://github.com/lukaszgryglicki).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bdfc15f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdfc15fb21328a1461191863777583d32c034077), 24 Aug 2017)</sup>

> ### `merge`: add a `--signoff` flag
>
> [Some projects require every commit, even merges, to be signed off](https://public-inbox.org/git/CAHv71zK5SqbwrBFX=a8-DY9H3KT4FEyMgv__p2gZzNr0WUAPUw@mail.gmail.com/T/#u).
>
> Because "`git merge`" does not have a "`--signoff`" option like "`git commit`" does, the user needs to add one manually when the command presents an editor to describe the merge, or later use "`git commit --amend --signoff`".
>
> Help developers of these projects by teaching "`--signoff`" option to
>   "`git merge`".

Answer (score 1):

A way is to merge and then "git commit --amend" the commit for altering the commit message OR to merge with "--no-commit" and then manually commit with a signed-off-by line.

A merge normally don't introduce new changes, thus, don't always need to be signed.